# Beginner: Output is different than expected

Tags: c#, class

I am trying to get a pre-determined output (designated as color and speed) from a private class. However, when I ask the program to write the line it prints out `Car_EX_3.Car`instead of the color and number.

This is my code so far

```
namespace Car_Ex_3
{
    class Car
    {
        private string colour;
        private double speed;
        public Car(string colour)
        {
            this.colour = colour;
        }
        public Car(string colour, double speed)
        {
            this.colour = colour;
            this.speed = speed;
        }
        public string GetColour()
        {
            return colour;
        }
        public double GetSpeed()
        {
            return speed;
        }
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Car car1 = new Car("red" + " " + 50d);

                Car car2 = new Car("Yellow" +" " + 60d);

                Console.WriteLine(car1);
                Console.WriteLine(car2);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't write any code that would print a color or number.  Learn about `ToString()`.

Comment: _Console.WriteLine(car1.GetColour());_

Comment: Shouldn't it be `new Car("Yellow", 60d);`

Comment: @Steve Thanks! that was it! I also had another error by doin a "+" instead of a "," on the main string

Comment: Write you class seperate instead of wrapping the program class inside the car class for a start.

Comment: You should add a ToString method to your class!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already many people mentioned: Overriding the `Object.ToString()` method would give you the desired results.

Every class in C# derives from the `System.Object` class, but the `.ToString()` method normally just prints the name of the instance's class. To prevent this, implement a new method into your `Car` class:

```
public override string ToString ()
{
     return "Car (Color: " + colour + ", Speed: " + speed.ToString() + ")";
}
```

or with `String.Format`:

```
public override string ToString ()
{
    return string.Format("Car (Color: {0}, Speed: {1})", colour, speed.ToString());
}
```

Comment: to make this cleaner you may want to have your code example return the string using the string.Format function vs all the Concatenating of value + string literals

Comment: I wasn't sure whether that was too advanced or not. Edited my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing in wrong way actually.

Correct way:

```
Car car1 = new Car("red", 50d);
Car car2 = new Car("Yellow", 60d);

Console.WriteLine("Car1 Color: " + car1.colour + " Number: " + car1.speed);
Console.WriteLine("Car2 Color: " + car2.colour + " Number: " + car2.speed);
```

You have to use constructor with 2 arguments, one argument color and second one is speed. 
In `Console.WrtieLine()` you were directly writing class object thats is why it was giving unwanted results(`Car_EX_3.Car`), because its telling you the type of object by its namespace and class name .
you have to access the `colour` and `speed` properties of `car1` and `car2` objects.

Initially your were doing `Car car1 = new Car("red" + " " + 50d);`, It is calling the one argument constrictor, not the two argument constructor, because `"red" + " " + 50d` will be converted to string by the compiler.

As suggested by Ian H. above, You can override `ToString()` or make own method to convert a composite type(your class object) to your required string format and use wherever you want in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just to go through the code:

```
// Don't forget to include the access modifier
class Car
{
private string colour;
private double speed;
// Is it valid to have just a color and not a speed as well?
public Car(string colour)
{
    this.colour = colour;
}
public Car(string colour, double speed)
{
    this.colour = colour;
    this.speed = speed;
}

// In C# this should be a property
public string GetColour()
{
    return colour;
}
public double GetSpeed()
{
    return speed;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Car car1 = new Car("red" + " " + 50d);

        Car car2 = new Car("Yellow" +" " + 60d);

        This is incorrect
        Console.WriteLine(car1);
        Console.WriteLine(car2);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Try the following instead:

```
public class Car
{
private string colour;
private double speed;
// Is it valid to have just a color and not a speed as well?
public Car(string colour)
{
    this.colour = colour;
    // Initialize it to 0.0
    speed = 0.0;
}
public Car(string colour, double speed)
{
    this.colour = colour;
    this.speed = speed;
}

// In C# this should be a property
public string Colour
{
    get { return colour; }
}
public double Speed
{
    get { return speed; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Car car1 = new Car("red" + " " + 50d);

        Car car2 = new Car("Yellow" +" " + 60d);

        // Do something like the following to print what you want
        Console.WriteLine(car1.Colour + " " + car1.Speed);
        Console.WriteLine(car2.Colour + " " + car2.Speed);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

As other people have mentioned, you can also accomplish this by overriding the ToString() method. Ian H. has an excellent code sample in his answer if that's the route you want to take.